# PHP changing date position

Tags: date, position

I have date like 24\12\2013

And want it to be 20131224

I want to use this code for barcode

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$date);
```

I know how to remove backlash but how the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use date format with php :

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('24\12\2013');
echo $date->format('Ymd');
?>
```